# Can't get nginx working in a docker-compose context with webpack-dev-server

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I'm playing with `docker-compose` and `nginx`, at which I am both pretty new. I have a front-end container and a back-end container and I want to use `nginx` to proxy requests to and between the two applications. So, I set up a minimal Dockerfile,

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80 443
```

and a minimal `default.conf`,

```
upstream fibclient {
  server fibclient:9000;
}

upstream fibserver {
  server fibserver:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://fibclient;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://fibserver;
  }
}
```

to bring `nginx` in my docker-compose file, here is the a snippet:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ...
nginx:
  restart: always
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    context: ./nginx
  ports:
    - '8000:80'
  depends_on:
    - fibclient
    - fibserver
fibserver:
  ...
fibclient:
  ...
```

Well I was expecting `nginx` to proxy requests to the two applications as I indicate in the `default.conf` but instead I am getting an `Invalid host header` error while trying to get `localhost:8000`. I read several posts and resources to solve this issue, but no luck for now. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** Could it be a webpack problem instead? Maybe webpack-dev-server (version `^3.11.0`) isn't able to solve requests that came from the nginx instance? Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'bin'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
};
```

which I simply launch this way: `"start": "webpack-dev-server"`.

Oh, if you want to have a look at the whole stuff, you can find it [here](https://github.com/fpezzati/fibsequence), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can lay my hands on this again. It turns out that wasn't a problem of how I configure `nginx`, but the containerized `webpack-dev-server`, just add the `host: '0.0.0.0', disableHostCheck: true` parameters in my `webpack.config.js`. Here is the relevant part:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'bin'),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be add server_name into :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
```

Comment: Hello! I tried, but no luck. It looks the nginx container can GET the fibclient (the container with the front end app) correctly by using curl, but using the proxy I can't get it from my host...

Comment: How was you access the app? Http://localhost:8000 , right ?

Comment: Yes! If you try the whole stuff, ignore the server app it is bugged in some way, I am just trying to track that bug down right now. Thanks!